# find_element_by_xpath does not return span class value

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

[image]

Hi,

I'm trying to scrape the value of the span `class = "ws-value"` (which is bounded in red in the Source Code picture). I have tried:

```
test = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//span[@class='ws-value']")
print test
```

but all I got was an empty list.

Can someone show me how to get the two ws-values? Many thanks!

Comment: Your, published, code should work, please post HTML and the rest of the code snippet (if any). Meanwhile, are you sure `test` is empty? Try `test[0]` or  `test[1]`

Comment: `test = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//span[@class='ws-value']")` will return the Node. What are you trying to print exactly? **84**, **69** ?

Comment: Hi, yes test is an empty list. there is nothing in test[0] and test[1]. And yes, I want to print 84, and 69.

Answer (score 1):

use `.text` method and this xpath

```
test = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(@class,'test')]").text
print test
```

You have to use if else condition also, if multiple nodes are there

Answer (score 0):

Use find_element instead of find_elements and `text` method to get the text

```
test = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[@class='ws-value']").text
print test
```

if you want to get all those element values then loop through it :

```
 test = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//span[@class='ws-value']")
 for x in test:
     print x.text
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. This still didn't work for me.

Comment: No. It just doesn't print out anything

Comment: Can you try `get_attribute('value')` instead of `.text` and let me know

Comment: It still didn't work. It now throw an Exception: NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[contains(@class,'ws-value')]"}

Answer (score 0):

You can try to apply [ExplicitWait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) as below to wait for presence of required `span` nodes and then get values with `text` property:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

test = [node.text for node in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, ".//span[@class='ws-value']")))]
```

Comment: @anna, any feedback?

Answer (score 0):

As per the `HTML` to print **`84`**, **`69`**, you can use the following block of code :

```
for test in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(By.XPATH, "//ul[@id='walkscore-target']/li//div[@class='ws-score']/a[@rel='nofollow']/span[@class='ws-value']")) :
    print(test.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. It still didn't work.

Comment: Updated my Answer to negate `NoSuchElementException`. Let me know the status.